# which is more efficient between video stream and image uploading?

Tags: video-streaming, webcam

My server needs to have access to webcams via browsers. WebRTC is a straightforward solution for the communication. But in my cases, the server does not really need a video stream. Two frames per second are ok, even 1 frame is not too bad. So another solution is that Javascript takes snaps with webcam and sends them to server.

My goal is to reduce lantecy. Which solution is better? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you're using it for... If you're going to really stick to a 1-3 frames per second, picture upload should be fine. If you need an accurate picture of what the user is doing, probably go with video. The reduced latency benefit decreases after 3 frames from my experience, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can set WebRTC frame per seconds. so you can maintain latency very well. both WebRTC and JavaScript is better. Just depend on you to adopt technique.